# gridview custom adapter search

Tags: android, search, gridview

i have grid view , and custom adapter i want to search the items that are in the grid view by a search view ,,,

the thing is i don't know how to implement a search view along with a custom adopter ,, because i have a click event in the custom adapter which is when the user clicks an item it downloads a pdf file form internet ,, how can i add search view that will search the grid view items in with the custom adapter click even running ,

i am new usually i copy and paste the code i am 30% new .

this is my main activity

```js
package com.alhaddadsoft.ammar.gridview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    GridView gv;
    GridView gv1;
    TextView newtext;
    Context context;
    ArrayList prgmName;
    public static String [] prgmNameList={"احمد عبده ماهر","احمد داوود","احمد صبحي منصور","لكشف الموروث اقرأ هذا أولا","الختان للذكور والاناث","الصادق النيهوم","الطريق إلى بيت المقدس","اوشو","بن فرناس","جمال البنا","جورج طرابيشي","زكريا اوزون", "سلامه موسى","سلسلة عندما نَطَقَ السراة","عبد الرزاق جبران","عبد الله القصيمي","علي الوردي","علي شريعتي","فاضل الربيعي","فرج فوده","كمال الصليبي","محمد اركون","محمد شحرور","محمد علي المحمود","محمود ابو ريه","نيازي عز الدين","هشام جعيط"
        ,"أبو الأعلى المودودي - الخلافة والملك","أسوار الصمت قراءة في الحقوق المدنية في السعودية لـ د. وليد الماجد","احمد امين - فجر الاسلام","اعمدة الحكمة السبعة . لورنس العرب","الارهابى ",
            " الاسلام واصول الحكم -- على عبد الرازق","الاسلام وجراب الحاوي . شاكر النابلسي","الاضافة النوعية القرانية.مصطفى بوهندي",
            "التأثير المسيحي في تفسير القران","التوراة اليهودية مكشوفة على حقيقتها","الخلافه الاسلاميه.محمد سعيد عشماوي","الدولة الاسلامية ،الجذور والتوحش عبدالباري عطوان","الدين واحتكار الحقيقه.واثق غازي","السادس من نوفمبر قيادة المراة للسيارة","السلطة في الاسلام لعبدالجواد حسين","السلفيون ايضا يدخلون النار.وليد طوغان","السنة بين الاصول والتاريخ ذويب رسالة دكتوراة","العقل الايماني","القران وثالوث الاستبداد.نشأت جعفر",
            "القران ولغة السريان. احمد علي الجمل","اللاهوت العربى-يوسف زيدان","المؤمن الصادق - إيريك هوفر","الملوك المحتسبون حجم صغير","امي كاملة عقل ودين","انتكاسة المسلمين الى الوثنية - سيد القمني","بالداخل . اشرف فياض","بالداخل . اشرف فياض","تاريخ نجد . بن غنام مؤرخ محمد بن عبدالوهاب","تحرير المرأه من عهد الرساله","تزييف الاسلام.انور اسحاق","جغرافية التوراة _زياد منى","حتى لا يعود جهيمان . توما ... غهامر . ستيفان لاكروا",
            "حكاية التدين السعودي . وحيد الغامدي","حواء والخطيئة","حوار حول القران وحده . محمد توفيق صدقي","رجم الزاني","طبائع الإستبداد ومصارع الإستعباد","عبد الرزاق عيد .. سدنة هياكل الوهم , نقد العقل الفقهي","عبيد بلا اغلال.تاريخ جزيرة العرب القريب","فتنة القول بتعليم البنات.عبدالله الوشمي","قدماء المصريين اول الموحدين","كارثة فلسطين . عبدالله التل","لعبة الامم","ما بعد الشيوخ ، انهيار ممالك الخليج","مابعد الصحوة.عبدالله الغذامي","مشكلة الحديث","معجزة اختيار اللفظ في القرآن",
            "مقالة العبودية الطوعية","من يجرؤ على الكلام .بول فندلي","نقد الخطاب الديني لنصر ابو زيد","نقد الخطاب السلفي ابن تيمية نموذجا.رائد السمهوري","ورثة محمد .جذور الخلاف السني الشيعي"


    };
    public static int [] prgmImages={R.drawable.folder_mac_icon,R.drawable.folder_mac_icon,R.drawable.folder_mac_icon,R.drawable.folder_mac_icon,R.drawable.folder_mac_icon,R.drawable.folder_mac_icon,R.drawable.folder_mac_icon,R.drawable.folder_mac_icon,R.drawable.folder_mac_icon,R.drawable.folder_mac_icon,R.drawable.folder_mac_icon,R.drawable.folder_mac_icon,R.drawable.folder_mac_icon,R.drawable.folder_mac_icon,R.drawable.folder_mac_icon,R.drawable.folder_mac_icon,R.drawable.folder_mac_icon,R.drawable.folder_mac_icon,R.drawable.folder_mac_icon,R.drawable.folder_mac_icon,R.drawable.folder_mac_icon,R.drawable.folder_mac_icon,R.drawable.folder_mac_icon,R.drawable.folder_mac_icon,R.drawable.folder_mac_icon,R.drawable.folder_mac_icon,R.drawable.folder_mac_icon
    ,R.drawable.book1,R.drawable.book2,R.drawable.book3,R.drawable.book4,R.drawable.book5,R.drawable.book6,R.drawable.book7,R.drawable.book8,R.drawable.book9,R.drawable.book10,R.drawable.book11,R.drawable.book12,R.drawable.book13,R.drawable.book14,R.drawable.book15,R.drawable.book16,R.drawable.book17,R.drawable.book18,R.drawable.book19,R.drawable.book20,R.drawable.book21_,R.drawable.book21,R.drawable.book22,R.drawable.book23,R.drawable.book24,R.drawable.book25,R.drawable.book26,R.drawable.book27,R.drawable.book28,R.drawable.book29,R.drawable.book30,R.drawable.book31,R.drawable.book32,R.drawable.book33,R.drawable.book34,R.drawable.book35,R.drawable.book36_,R.drawable.book36,R.drawable.book37,R.drawable.book38,R.drawable.book39,R.drawable.book40,R.drawable.book41,R.drawable.book42,R.drawable.book43,R.drawable.book44,R.drawable.book45,R.drawable.book46,R.drawable.book47,R.drawable.book48,R.drawable.book49,R.drawable.book50,

    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        gv=(GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
        gv.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this, prgmNameList, prgmImages));


       
      


    }
    public void openactivity1(){
        edittext();
        //Intent i = new Intent(this, AhmedDaod.class);
       // startActivity(i);

}
public void edittext(){
  //  newtext =  (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
   // newtext.setText("hello");
}
}
```

This is my CustomAdapter acteivity

```js
package com.alhaddadsoft.ammar.gridview;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    String[] result;
    Context context;


    int[] imageId;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;


    String dwnload_file_path;
    String file_name;
    String imageViewD;
    String textViewD;

    GridView gridview;
    public CustomAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, String[] prgmNameList, int[] prgmImages ) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        result = prgmNameList;
        context = mainActivity;
        imageId = prgmImages;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return result.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public class Holder {
        TextView tv;
        ImageView img;
        TextView edit ;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final Holder holder = new Holder();
        View rowView;


        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.programlist, null);
        holder.tv = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.img = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        holder.tv.setText(result[position]);
        holder.img.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
        rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               // Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked " + result[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // String displayedText = ((TextView)((LinearLayout)myToast.getView()).getChildAt(0)).getText().toString();
                try {
                    if (result[position].equals("أبو الأعلى المودودي - الخلافة والملك")) {


                        new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                                .setTitle("تحميل الكتاب")
                                .setMessage("هل تريد تحميل الكتاب?")
                                .setPositiveButton("تحميل", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        // continue with delete
                                        dwnload_file_path = "http://www.jouhinabooks.com/get_file.php?id=470";
                                        file_name = "book1.pdf";
                                        imageViewD = "book1";
                                        textViewD = result[position];
                                        Downloadmethode();

                                    }
                                })
                                .setNegativeButton("رجوع", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        // do nothing
                                    }
                                })
                                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                                .show();




                        //Intent intent= new Intent(context, AhmedDaod.class);
                       // intent.putextra("your_extra","your_class_value");
                        //context.startActivity(intent);


                        //MainActivity openactivity = new MainActivity();
                       // openactivity.openactivity1();
                        //edittext.setText("hello");
                    }

                } catch (final Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "error  ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }

        });

        return rowView;

    }
    public void Downloadmethode(){
        Intent d = new Intent(context, DownloadBook.class);
        d.putExtra("dwnload_file_path", dwnload_file_path);
        d.putExtra("file_name", file_name);
        d.putExtra("imageViewD",imageViewD);
        d.putExtra("textViewD",textViewD);
        context.startActivity(d);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I implemented the search feature. Create two Lists, the searchList and the backUpList.

```
backUpList = loadMyData();
searchList.addAll(backUpList);
```

Now you have two lists that contain the same data. And because the lists contain only references to the objects there is no extra memory being used. Then feed the searchList to the adapter instead of the actual list.

```
adapter = new CustomAdapter(searchList*/,...other inputs*/);
gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And now when you want to search in your data you empty your search list and search in you back up list. If an object should be shown then add it in your search list. Then notify the adapter and your search results are shown.

```
searchList.clear();
searchList.addAll(backUpList);
for(CustomObject object:backUpList){
    if(meetsSearchCriteria(object)){
        searchList.add(object);
    }
}
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

And adjust the rest of your code to work with the searchList instead of the actual data list.

You must change your adapter to take an ArrayList of objects as input and not a table as your code shows. Tables do not support changes in their size after their creation.